# Where can I learn about comet and client push methods?

Tags: comet

I'd like to learn how to implement basic "comet" or client push methods 
something like meebo 
from server and client side , where can I find good and clear spec?
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you didn't put enough effort into asking the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you're not really specifying the technology you would like to work in ... But these links proved to be very helpful for me:

- [Ajax Push(like) Chat with Comet](http://niryariv.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/the-long-poll-implementing-ajax-chat-with-comet/)
- [Creating Comet applications with ASP.Net](http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/07/08/creating-comet-applications-with-aspnet/)
- [COMET (or Reverse AJAX) based Grid Control for ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CometGrid.aspx)

Comment: what do you mean by technology ? server ? 
i will build module in side nginx server

Answer (score 2):

Comet is a big term, and there are many different implementations. There isn't a particular single specifications, it is more of a concept or idea.

I had to do a project with server push, and I came across a couple of attempts to come up with specifications, such as [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html).

Eventually, I found the best I could do was check out what others are currently doing, there are a couple of nice projects such as [Orbited](http://orbited.org/) and [Juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/). Then, implement my own solution.

I built my own solution using [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) and [SocketBridge](http://matthaynes.net/blog/2008/07/17/socketbridge-flash-javascript-socket-bridge/).